# Magento Enterprise Slow Solr Search Perfomance

Tags: magento, search, solr, catalog, magento-1.13

We've 2300 products in our magento store. We implemented magento enterprise default solr search, search is working fine but it is too slow. We purchased x medium aws instance for solr. I am not sure which parameters are making search too slow.

Answer (score 0):

There was a third party extension which was blocking communication between magento and solr, i've removed that extension and it is working fine now.